# LyX: Changing layout inside table cell

Tags: tables, lyx, lyx-layouts

I'm using LyX to write a simple report. I had some paragraph written as a "description list", when I thought that it may look better as a table instead.

I created a table, and when I copied the text inside the table cell, it kept the "Description" layout, and is still shown as such. I want to change that back to a plain layout, but the drop down widget to select the layout is disabled. Similarly, keyboard shortcuts say "command disabled".

Other than editing the .lyx file manually, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Can't you change the list to standard layout before copying it to the table? Oh, and welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I can do that, of course. As well as I can modify the .lyx file directly, which is what I ended up doing in the end. My question was more like, for the future, is there a "right way" I am supposed to do this, or is there a good reason why I shouldn't? Let's say, in the future, I may actually want a bullet list inside a cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following action:

```
command-sequence inset-modify tabular set-pwidth 10cm; layout standard; inset-modify tabular set-pwidth
```

To run it directly, make sure your cursor is in the cell in the table, press alt+x for the mini-buffer, paste it in, and hit return.

If you like this, you can make a shortcut by going to the following:

> Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts

However, I hope that you don't like this. The best thing to do is to [report this as a bug](http://www.lyx.org/trac). This is a hack and you should not rely on it.

The reason for this behavior is the following:
The mechanism that determines whether you can modify the layout is `ForcePlain`. For more detail, search for that word in

> Help > Customization

It is hardcoded for table insets and is determined as follows (as shown in `src/insets/InsetTabular.cpp`):

```
bool InsetTableCell::forcePlainLayout(idx_type) const
{
    return !isFixedWidth;
}
```

Thus, the hack works as follows: it changes to a fixed width, changes the layout to standard, then removes the fixed width.

If you want a list inside a table in the future (asked in a comment to the question), the correct way is to make a fixed width and then change the layout.

Note that to edit the width graphically, place the cursor in the table and go to

> Edit > Table Settings

Comment: Thank you so much! Your "hack" works, but as you said it's a hack, so a bug report is the right thing to do. Also, if it happens again, now I know I just need to set the table to fixed width, then back. In fact, while trying to reproduce the problem, and playing with fixed/variable width with a "Enumerate" layout inside the cell, LyX actually crashed...

Comment: If you can provide detailed steps by which you can repeat the crash, that bug report would be very important. Note that this should be posted as a separate bug report.

Comment: Filed a [bug report](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8782).

Comment: @Daniele looks good. I will confirm that it's on the latest development version also. Thanks for doing that!

Comment: Thanks to you! Cannot reproduce the crash, maybe lyx saved a crash report somewhere?

Comment: @Daniele LyX cannot but I think Mac does. I know nothing about Macs but try here: http://support.kaspersky.com/2861

Comment: I'm actually on Ubuntu 12.10... if it happens again, I'll try my best to gather information and file a bug.

Comment: @Daniele In that case, it depends on your `ulimit` for whether there is a core file dumped when there's a crash. email to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org if you want more info on this and on how to get information from the core file. Also since you're using Ubuntu you should consider using the PPA. It's very easy to use the development version or latest stable version without having to give up your current version (which is a couple years old now). They can be both installed with no risk. To do this, see the instructions here:
http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3